# PHP MySQL multiple image URL fields array

Tags: php, mysql

In building a website for a friend the database has a row with 39 fields for images.
In the field is the name of the image (e.g. "my_image.jpg") not the image itself (BLOB).
i.e.: image_01, image_02, image_03 and so forth.

I have PHP generating the while loop and getting the information without problems.
I'm trying to get all the images into one array so I can display the pictures from that one row as a gallery.

I hope someone can offer me a way forward as I've tried without success.

from while loop:

```
$MEDIA_IMAGE_00 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_00"];
$MEDIA_IMAGE_01 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_01"];
$MEDIA_IMAGE_02 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_02"];
```

I need to echo out as

```
["propimages/$MEDIA_IMAGE_00", "", "", "$MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00"],
["propimages/$MEDIA_IMAGE_01", "", "", "$MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01"],
["propimages/$MEDIA_IMAGE_02", "", "", "$MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_02"]
```

for them to display in a gallery.

EDIT:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlSearch)){ 
   $propid = $row["propid"];
   $MEDIA_IMAGE_00 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_00"];
   $MEDIA_IMAGE_01 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_01"];
   $MEDIA_IMAGE_02 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_02"];

   $MEDIA_IMAGE_33 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_33"];
   $MEDIA_IMAGE_34 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_34"];
   $MEDIA_IMAGE_35 = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_35"];
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `$MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00` from ?

Comment: in the database along with all images

Comment: post the whileloop to recommended code instead of writing it outselves.

Comment: posted the while loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `$propid` is what identifies the row itself and that 'MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT' is available in the same row:

```
$properties = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlSearch)) {
    $propid = $row["propid"];
    $images = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 35; ++$i) {
        $imageId = "MEDIA_IMAGE_" . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        if ($row[$imageId]) {
            $images[] = array(
                $row[$imageId],
                '',
                '',
                $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_" . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)],
            );
        }
    }
    $properties[] = array(
        'id' => $propid,
        'images' => $images,
    );

    echo json_encode($properties);
```

It generates a list of properties, each having an id and an array of images; each image comprises the location (I guess) and the title / description.

Comment: Hi Jack thank you for your post, sorry for the delay... I've added the code and it's showing     [{"images":[["53384_2_IMG_00.jpg","","",""] etc... going to have a play and hope it works but this is what i needed so i can see so thank you very much :) I'm still learning..lol

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for this code it has got me alot closer to where i need to be...
Could you direct me to displaying the code like this    ["propimages/53384_2_IMG_00.jpg","","",""], and to only get values if the field has a image url value :)

At this time i have it showing imgs    ["propimages\/53384_2_IMG_00.jpg","","",""], but if property only has say 4 images i return empty     ["","","",""]

Thank you for your time Jack it's grately appreciated !

Comment: lmao and i was looking around trying to find an update button...lol
Never mind.. Thank you so much for the Update Jack your a star m8 i really appreciate your help and time :) Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build an array of images in your while loop ?

```
$images = array()

$i = 0;

While(...) {
$images[] = $row["MEDIA_IMAGE_0$i"];
$i++;
[...]
}
```

The  you get an array that you ca use in a foreach and display your row(s). On the principle that should work, i think ;)

Comment: Or maybe: $key = 'MEDIA_IMAGE_0'.$i; and then $images[] = $row[$key];

Comment: code is missing stuff, almost pseudocode. we need to check user's code

Comment: Yeah, it is a PRINCIPLE ! As written.